# Insert a cell in a specific index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the object of the row that I want to insert the cell.
What I can't do is select the specific `column` to insert the data.

```
<ul class="my_list">
   <li>
      <h3 >Eusebio Rice</h3>                
      <ul class="my_sublist">
         <li data-time="14:30:00" data-day="Sun">Discipline I</li>
         <li data-time="14:30:00" data-day="Tue">Discipline II</li>                                        
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul> 


<table id="prof-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>HORÁRIO</th>
         <th data-dia="Sun">Sunday</th>
         <th data-dia="Tue">Tuesday</th>
         <th data-dia="Wed">Wednesday</th>
         <th data-dia="Thu">Thursday</th>
         <th data-dia="Fri">Friday</th>                 
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>08:30 ~ 10:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10:30 ~ 12:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14:30 ~ 16:30</td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what i've done so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".my_list h3").click(function(event){
            var obj = event.target;

            //loop through all the disciplines and get their name and time
            $(obj).next().find('li').each(function(){
                var disciplina = $(this).text().trim();
                var discipline_time = $(this).data('time');         
                var time_range = $('#prof-table').find("tr td:first-child"); //take the first column
                var day_range = $('#prof-table').find("tr th");

                time_range = time_range.map(function(idx, row){
                var time_period = $(row).text().split(' ~ '); //split the columns data to start and stop time
                    //create a new object that keeps the time range and index
                    return {index: idx, from: time_period[0], to: time_period[1]};
                });
                .each(time_range, function(indx, range){
                   if( (range.from+":00")<= discipline_time && (range.to+"00") >= discipline_time){
                   var myRow = document.getElementById("prof-table").rows[range.index + 1]; //range.index pega rows
                   console.log(myRow); // My row element
```

So, how could I do something to loop through the days of the week and compare with discipline's day of the week. ALSO, is that possible to insert a cell on position 3 of the row without have to insert it on position 1 and 2 first ? If it's the only way, is there a better way to do it instead of a for loop ?

Comment: Why I can't see the `$(".prof-list h3")` object in your code? Or is it `$(".my_list h3")`? And `data-day="Sue"` should be `data-day="Sun"`, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry about that. Forgot to change that.